# Error updating Room field using TypeConverter with a list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

It works fine when getting the list from Room but when i try to update it it gives me this error:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE reminderconfig SET alarmDays = ?,?,?,?,?,?,? WHERE id = 1`

Here is the query:

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
@Query("UPDATE reminderconfig SET alarmDays = :days WHERE id = 1")
suspend fun updateAlarmDays(days: List<Int>)
```

Here is my Converters class:

```
class Converters {
@TypeConverter
fun fromString(value: String): List<Int> {
    val type = object: TypeToken<List<Int>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson(value, type)
}

@TypeConverter
fun fromArrayList(list: List<Int>): String {
    val type = object: TypeToken<List<Int>>() {}.type
    return Gson().toJson(list, type)
}
}
```

And here is the Database:

```
@Database(entities = [ReminderConfig::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ReminderDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun reminderDao(): ReminderDao
}
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
class ReminderConfig(

@PrimaryKey
val id: Int = 1,

@ColumnInfo
val timeInterval: Int = DEFAULT_INTERVAL_REPEATING,

@ColumnInfo
val startTime: Int = DEFAULT_START_TIME_PERIOD,

@ColumnInfo
val endTime: Int = DEFAULT_END_TIME_PERIOD,

@ColumnInfo
val alarmDays: List<Int> = listOf(0,1,2,3,4,5)
)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your entity class?

Comment: Sure, i just added it.

Comment: Hmmm... for some reason, Room is thinking that `alarmDays` is an `Int`, not a `List<Int>`, at least in that `updateAlarmDays()` function.

Comment: yeah i looked at the build impl and the update query does not use the TypeConverter for some reason, i checked with the insert query and it does use the TypeConverter

Comment: @Joaco I ran into the same issue this evening. I _think_ this is a bug as general read queries work successfully. It's only when UPDATE is used that the TypeConverter is ignored in the generated file.

I've opened a bug against Room's issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176448260

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and is fixed the latest Room Alpha release (`2.3.0-alpha04`).

[Google Issue Tracker Link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176448260)